On change event for input select isnt firing
I am having the below inputselect and all I want is a cascading ones, so if you choose a branch, the tables will be filtered. I've been stuck for over a week and not sure why its not working.
Tried onchange and bind-Value and just value and its still not working
Any ideas on how can I fix this??
Also, how can i debug such an issue??? It should be easier to see the error somewhere as it just goes blank without mentioning whats the error
@page "/Sample"
@attribute [StreamRendering]
@inject IConfiguration config
@using JoryApp.Components.Models
@using JoryApp.Dynamics
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using JoryApp.Data
@using Blazored.LocalStorage


<AuthorizeView Context="authContext">
    <EditForm Context="editContext" Model="Order" Method="Post" OnValidSubmit="CreateOrder">

        <h2>Create a sample order</h2>
        <hr />
        <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">

              <InputSelect class="form-select form-select-sm"
                         TValue="string"
                         Value="Order.Branch"
                         ValueChanged="@( 
(string s) => OnValueChanged(s))"
                         ValueExpression="( () => Order.Branch )">
                <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected>Filter By</option>
                @if (Branches != null)
                {
                    @foreach (Branch branch in Branches )
                    {
                        <option value="@branch.jr_branchid">@branch.jr_name</option>
                    }
                }
            </InputSelect>
        <label class="form-label">Branch</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.Branch" class="text-danger" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="Order.Table" class="form-control" aria-required="true" placeholder="your branch">
            @if (CurrentTables != null)
            {
                @foreach (Table tbl in CurrentTables)
                {
                    <option value="@tbl.jr_tableid">@tbl.jr_name</option>
                }
            }
        </InputSelect>            <label class="form-label">Table</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Order.Table" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
           <div>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create Order</button>
    </div>


</EditForm>

@code {

private EditContext? editContext;

private string? errorMessage;

[CascadingParameter]
private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private OrderModel Order { get; set; } = new();

private List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
private Dynamics.Account? currentAccount;
private Dynamics.Contact? currentContact;

private List<Table> CurrentTables { get; set; }


public async Task OnValueChanged(string branchId)
{
    Order.Branch = branchId;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(branchId) && currentContact != null)
    {
        await RefreshTables(branchId);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentTables = null;
    }
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}


private async Task RefreshTables(string selectedBranchId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBranchId))
    {
        List<Table> tables = Dynamics.BranchesData.GetTables(config, selectedBranchId, currentContact.parentcustomerid_account.accountid);
        if (tables != null)
        {
            CurrentTables = tables;
        }
    }
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

public void CreateOrder()
{

}

}

Based on my reading of your code, you're trying to build two select controls where the first select filters the values available in the second.  Based on that I've pointed you to another question and answer that answers that question.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis , I've seen those answers you mentioned and I tried them but its still not working, I hope you can re-open the question as it's been for over a week and any help is really appreciated

NP.  I've voted to reopen. I've just seen @attribute [StreamRendering].  Is this a SSR page? If so why isn't it interactively rendered?

I've created this project as Server rending, I am using stream rendering because most of the data inside the page is API calls

Where have you set interactivity?  Per Page/Component? This page should almost certainly be interactive.  "data inside the page is API calls" is not a reason to use StreamRendering.

it's all in page, i am not using any specific component, whatever code you see is the only code there

This is a statically rendered page.  You can't do interactive stuff such as updating the select lists in a SSR.  The page needs to be interactive.

cany you provide me with any link/article that explains this?? also, what change i can make it to the page to make it interactive? the online videos that are implementing this use exactly the same code as mine

Got it, all was needed to add @rendermode InteractiveServer at the top, thank you!

All was needed is to add @rendermode InteractiveServer to the top, thanks to MrC aka Shaun Curtis for explaining that in the comments below
